# The difference between 2 negative numbers gives negative result instead of positive [SSRS]

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2014, I have SSRS report with matrix inside. 
Problem: difference between 2 negative numbers doesn't give sum

The expression of field is:

```
= ReportItems!Textbox1.value - ReportItems!Textbox2.value
```

In report it looks like:

```
 Textbox1  | Textbox2 | Expression result |  
 ------------------------------------------
    -73    |   -170   |       -97         |
```

So i have result **-97** instead of **97**.
How I can fix this problem?

Comment: I would expect `+97` as a result actually, not 243.

Comment: yes, it was mistake, i need to get +97 instead of -97

Answer (score 0):

that is weird i tied table, matrix and text boxes all seem to work fine. i'm using ssrs 2012 though.

you could try something like

```
=(ReportItems!Textbox1.Value - ReportItems!Textbox2.Value) * iif( ReportItems!Textbox1.Value > ReportItems!Textbox2.Value,1,-1)
```